# Does my code get Valgrind to be crashed?

Tags: c++, valgrind

Enabling one of my team's class instance running on valgrind
shows the message below and it terminates with no reasonable report (none of invalid memory read/write either).

**Error message:**

```
--6941-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV)     - exiting
--6941-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x17E2C998;  sp: 0x100fff0e10

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal

host stacktrace:
==6941==    at 0x58095C33: get_bszB_as_is (m_mallocfree.c:303)
==6941==    by 0x58095C33: get_bszB (m_mallocfree.c:315)
==6941==    by 0x58095C33: vgPlain_arena_free (m_mallocfree.c:2109)
==6941==    by 0x58052843: release_oldest_block (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:169)
==6941==    by 0x58052843: create_MC_Chunk (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:212)
==6941==    by 0x58052A0B: vgMemCheck_new_block (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:388)
==6941==    by 0x58052BD9: vgMemCheck___builtin_new     (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:417)
==6941==    by 0x580DE7B3: do_client_request (scheduler.c:1866)
==6941==    by 0x580DE7B3: vgPlain_scheduler (scheduler.c:1433)
==6941==    by 0x580ED106: thread_wrapper (syswrap-linux.c:103)
==6941==    by 0x580ED106: run_a_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:156)
==6941==    by 0x580ED39A: vgModuleLocal_start_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:320)
==6941==    by 0x5811711D: ??? (in /lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==6941==    by 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEE: ???
==6941==    by 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEE: ???
==6941==    by 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEE: ???
```

So I guessed that user code(means my teams) messed up a `valgrind`'s memory region.
It is possible?

Also I have tried to find out what is wrong with that code on address-sanitizer but it doesn't report any issue.

How can I begin to dig this issue?

Comment: Kindly add the `valgrind` options that you used and the portion of the code that you believe is causing this.

Comment: valgrind --track-origins=yes --error-limit=no --log-file=valgrind.log is the options and the source code is big (including some extra modules and dependencies) so can't upload every files

Comment: and I am looking for the portion of the code causing this issue.
valgrind report doesn't help me where I start to look at :(

Comment: Did you try with `--leak-check=full` and `--show-leak-kinds=all`?

Comment: I'm guessing the get_bszb* functions are your code. Start by showing those.

Comment: @Azeem I just tried but doesn't show helpful log.

Comment: @rubenvb Hmm that code is part of valgrind.

Comment: Which platform is this on? And which version of Valgrind are you using?

Comment: As valgrind runs your program in a sandbox, it should catch all your SIGSEGV generated by your program. If valgrind get a SIGSEGV, it means that valgrind has a bug, or maybe, your program does something bad which valgrind is not able to catch (because it is cannot be catched by some reason). Have you tried it without `--track-origins`? Maybe that triggers the error. You might want to contact valgrind developers, so they can fix the problem.

Comment: @PaulFloyd  os : ubuntu 16 64bit valgrind 3.13.0 are together I use.

Comment: @geza Without --track-origins, Valgrind rarely shows invalid memory access log that seems doesn't make sense before it crash with above internal error log.

A couple of try digging with valgrind and gdb I found that some memory region is corrupted suddenly. (that's why valgrind invalid memory report seems doesn't make sense. After an initialization, that memory region should stay with allocated const instance. still don't know what code writes over this :( but I think it is enough to start to dig :) )
So It is not valgrind bug, just it doesn't catch what happend.
Thank you!

Comment: @jay: one of valgrind's purpose is to catch memory overwrite errors. On paper, it must catch all overwrites. If it crashes because the client (your program) overwrites memory, then it is a bug of valgrind. The only exception is if this overwrite is impossible to catch for some reason (or it is known that it is not catched). The log you provided does make sense, because it is a stacktrace of valgrind itself (**host** stacktrace), not of your program.

Comment: @geza without --track-origins, valgrind shows more about invalid memory access but there is no code works as the report says. That's why I said a log of valgrind doesn't make sense. :) And yes you are right. Above attached valgrind log does make sense. Sorry for my poor english. 
anyway I found that the code causing this issue, heap allocated memory is set for thread stack by pthread API and the size is too small also no memory protection option(such as mprotect).
Code running over the small stack makes everything mess up including valgrind I think.
By the way thank you for your help!

Comment: @jay: I see :) No problem, I'm glad you found the problem! If you have the time, you can report this issue to valgrind developers, they may be able to improve their already amazing tool.

Comment: @geza "no code works as the report says" means the address and the variables are valid at that moment. I checked that addresses printing its value inside in gdb.
In this case, I think valgrind report says something wrong but not exactly what it is.

Comment: @gaze Yes I'm looking for valgrind mailing list to issue this one :) thank you again!